# How to use PredicateBuilder together with Inner Join

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Database
[image]
SQL

```
    SELECT * FROM City as a
      inner join Country as b
      on a.CountryCode= b.Code
      where b.CountryName like %countryName%
```

LINQ

```
from city in db.Set<City>()
join country in db.Set<Country>() on city.CountryCode equals country.Code
where DbFunctions.Like(country.Name, searchParam.SearchValue)
select city;
```

How can I apply the LINQ into PredicateBuilder which is going use for the search function for the later on.

```
var Predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<City>(true);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParam.SearchValue))
{
   switch (searchParam.SearchBy)
   {
      case "SearchCity":
        Predicate = Predicate.And(x =>
        x.Name.Contains(searchParam.SearchValue)
        );
        break;
      default:
        break;
   }
}
```

I tested with this line in order to display all the corresponding data for my datatable

```
result = querys.Where(a => a.CountryCode.Contains(searchParamInString.SearchValue));
```

But **CountryCode** still didn't equals to **Code** because when I tried using

> a.Code

it still display City doesn't contain Code

Comment: Why predicate builder? Without that i know to do that.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Bcs when i just add the **LINQ** code into the switch case, when I pressed my search button nothing will come out. So I think that is there a way to let LINQ apply into predicate builder

Comment: Do you have navigation properties? Ca you post your model?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv had edited the question, pls refer to it , it just a really simple Model

Comment: Model as a class, not a table. `City` and `Country` classes.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv So is One City can refer to One Country while, One Country can refer to Many Country, had added the picture

Comment: What I'm, trying to get from you - do you have navigation properties defined or not. Images wont help, just post class definition.

Comment: "CountryCode still didn't equals to Code" -- what does this mean? And what does that have to do with PredicateBuilder? This question is very unclear, please try rewriting it.